# Custom Scroll Buttons for Input Text In Lua

Tags: lua, custom-scrolling

Please the problem i am facing now is that, i want to create two buttons to scroll text in an input box left and right using lua, especially when part of the text is hidden in the input box. I know this can be done using the left and right arrows on the keyboard, but what i need is how to do this in a custom way, using one button for left and one for right.
Actually, i don't know if i should even say how to control cursor movement using two buttons in a form of a scrollbar. However, which ever way it's clear, how can i do this in lua language, after the buttons have been created please?

Comment: As the base Lua language has no support for gui interfaces,  it would help to know what environment you are using Lua in, for example WOW or Corona or something else.

Comment: @ Jane: Please, i'm using the personal edition of autoplay studio, so please help me out.

Comment: @ Jane T: Please, i'm using the personal edition of autoplay. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Autoplay is not one I have come across.  You may be best looking at the controls available on your input box as I have not seen a way to do what you are looking for on standard windows controls.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/). It's dedicated Lua GUI library, and it certainly have functions like this.